# custom container is corrupted and it is being shown as multiple copies with names having Document IDs

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I have custom control with name as "New_request " . The application was running quite smoothly Until I find that the custom control is not opening and it is giving below error while opening :

*Could not open the editor: Could not parse the .xsp-config file named CustomControls/New_request.xsp-config in the project C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data\workspace\lotusapp_2fPARCO\apps_5cit_5cIT-Resource_5cResourceAccessApplication.nsf.*

Also the designer is showing multiple copies with same name . I opened the Package Explorer view  and it is showing multiple copies of New_Request and each copy name has different Document ID  e.g

New_request(0ADAD0BF2462564045257EC3002DD4DB).xsp

Comment: Seems we have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297280/conflicting-class-files

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the source to an editor (open the xsp file from Windows Explorer to get that). Then delete all copied of your custom control, the xsp-config and the .metadata file from Package Explorer. Then create a new custom control and paste your source in. (If you have custom properties you can edit the .xsp-config file to get that. Then once you have re-created the custom control, open the .xsp-config from Package Explorer and paste in your old code.)